# Creating a subverson repository not possible because button is grayed out?

Tags: tortoisesvn, repository

as you can see in the image I attached here:

**http://img202.imageshack.us/img202/6497/subversion.png**

the button to browse the DIR to set the repository directory is grayed out, but why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear because you have never entered a repository before.  That button is for navigating within a repository that is in the text box to the left of that button.  Type it in manually.  Then it will remember it in future checkouts and you can then press that button to navigate it.

If your intent is to create a repository, you are selecting the wrong function.  Select "create repository here" in the TortoiseSVN context menu.

Comment: I created a folder in C:\MyRepository and C:\MyWorkingCopy

Then I created a Repository in the above MyRepository. After I went to the MyWorkingCopy and did a SVN Checkout to get the data I could have put in the MyRepository. Then this happened =>

Command: Checkout from C://MyRepository, revision HEAD, Fully recursive, Externals included  
Error: Unrecognized URL scheme for 'c://myrepository'  

What is wrong?

Comment: You need to address the repository as:

FILE:///C:/MyRepository

Comment: that worked! now I added a .zip file to test the commit function. Subversion said its successfully uploaded, but I can not find this .zip file in the MyRepository folder ???

Comment: now I uploaded a 100 mb video .wmv file to find it easier and I found it! Its not a .wmv its a file without extension?? What format is it? Can I adjust suversion somehow to save files in the original format not this octet gay stream? a its binary format... gotta tune subversion then...

thx Amardeep!

Comment: The basic idea of a version controlled repository is that files are not stored in raw form.  As you make changes and commit them, subversion will store only delta changes, not the whole file again.  You access them via your working directory.  The repository files are not supposed to be accessed directly.